# Verilog If else "Signal not a constant" error

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

I am trying to instantiate modules inside various if else statements but i am getting the error with the first argument in the if parenthesis "signal is not a constant".All my arguments in the parenthesis of my if and if else statements are input wires,and i can't figure whats wrong
Thanks

I've tried passing the signals from a matrix to a single input for each position of the matrix but that didn't work either
Heres my some of my code below
The error is as follows:[Synth 8-35] 'neuron_valid11' is not a constant

```
`include "include.v"

module FeedForward(
    //Input
    input wire[`dataWidth-1:0]              sensor1,
    input wire[`dataWidth-1:0]              sensor2,
    input wire[`dataWidth-1:0]              sensor3,
    input wire[`dataWidth-1:0]              sensor4,
    input wire[`dataWidth-1:0]              sensor5,
    input wire[`dataWidth-1:0]              sensor6,
    input wire neuron_valid11,
    input wire neuron_valid12,
    input wire neuron_valid13,
    input wire neuron_valid14,
    input wire neuron_valid15,
    input wire neuron_valid16,
    input wire neuron_valid17,
    input wire neuron_valid18,
    input wire neuron_valid21,
    input wire neuron_valid22,
    input wire neuron_valid23,
    input wire neuron_valid24,
    input wire neuron_valid25,
    input wire neuron_valid26,
    input wire neuron_valid27,
    input wire neuron_valid28,
    input wire[(`dataWidth/2)-1:0]          targetVals
);
wire [7:0] weightValue;
wire [7:0] biasValue;
wire [7:0] out;
integer Loop;
wire ActiveN1;
wire ActiveN2;
wire ActiveN3;
wire ActiveN4;
wire ActiveN5;
wire ActiveN6;
wire ActiveN7;
wire ActiveN8;

wire reset;

localparam IDLE = 'd0,
           SEND = 'd1;
wire [`numNeuronLayer1-1:0] o1_valid;
wire [`numNeuronLayer1*`dataWidth-1:0] x1_out;
reg [`numNeuronLayer1*`dataWidth-1:0] holdData_1;
reg [`dataWidth-1:0] out_data_1;
reg data_out_valid_1;



if(neuron_valid11==1&&neuron_valid12==1&&neuron_valid13==1&&neuron_valid14==0&&neuron_valid15==1&&neuron_valid16==0&&neuron_valid17==0&&neuron_valid18==0)begin
Layer_1 #(.NN(`numNeuronLayer1),.numWeight(`numWeightLayer1),.dataWidth(`dataWidth),.layerNum(1),.sigmoidSize(`sigmoidSize),.weightIntWidth(`weightIntWidth),.actType(`Layer1ActType)) l1(
    .ActiveN1(1),
    .ActiveN2(1),
    .ActiveN3(1),
    .ActiveN4(0),
    .ActiveN5(1),
    .ActiveN6(0),
    .ActiveN7(0),
    .ActiveN8(0),
    .clk(s_axi_aclk),
    .rst(reset),
    .weightValue(weightValue),
    .biasValue(biasValue),
    .sensor1(sensor1),
    .sensor2(sensor2),
    .sensor3(sensor3),
    .sensor4(sensor4),
    .sensor5(sensor5),
    .sensor6(sensor6),
    .o_valid(o1_valid),
    .x_out(x1_out)
);
end
```

Comment: how are *numNeuronLayer1* and *dataWidth* defined?

Comment: They are defined in a seperate file if you see at the top of the file, the file that i include the "include.v" I defined there a lot of my constant variables

Comment: This is not enough. **How** are they defined in this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is

```
// If a wire equals 1
if(neuron_valid11==1...)begin
   // Declare a module instance
   Layer_1 #(..)(...);
end
```

You can't say 'while the design is running, if this wire has a certain value==1 then these modules exist in my design' - doesn't make sense. The module is a physical thing, fixed there or not, not popping in and out of existence.

You can at compile time do 'if MY_PARAM=SOMETHING begin, then instantiate your module' as long as the value is constant (as your error says). See https://www.chipverify.com/verilog/verilog-generate-block.

Or perhaps you want to select/mux signals into your module (maybe you want it disconnected/disabled sometimes and not others based on some condition). You would do that inside a always block, ex. checking `if(neuron_valid11==1` and driving signals that connect to your (always-existing) module instance. https://www.chipverify.com/verilog/verilog-4to1-mux

Comment: thank you so much, sorry if my code looks kinda stupid but i've had to learn verilog by my one in a very limited amount of time and i still lack in the basic understanding of hardware oriented coding, i have actually muxed the inputs to the layers and seems to work fine (as of syntax)